# Is Astrology mentioned in Vedas?

Tags: scripture, vedas, astrology

Please give references.

If not, then why do people believe in it, or why is it used in marriage ?

Comment: Astrology is mentioned in lots of text, I mean lot.Take rudryamal tantra which states about the dasha especially yogini dasha, kulavarna tantra, purans. I cant confirm the story i heard but astrology was taught by kartik swami (subramanian) to Agstya rushi, the shlokas are not yet completely translated and described in any books. Now coming to part of marriage- its duly because we want to prevent two people with same doshaa (deficiency or bad combination) live together. If it happens the problem amplifies and may lead to sadness. Remember Divorce is not the only issue, there are lot unspoken.

Comment: 2nd comment, we also have extend the use of astrology beyond its applicable accuracy for a market needs. Earlier the mantra given to the student by the guru was dependent on the nakshatra he is born in. Belief is a personal part of everyone. If you believe then believe it, if not then dont. One misconception that people have is horoscope matching is based on Guna system which simply is not true, the real thing lies in the combination of planets which is ignored by many today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

[Jyothisha](http://vedicheritage.gov.in/vedangas/jyotisha/) is one of the 6 Veda Angas (auxiliary of Vedas).

It's main purpose is to predict positions of gruhas in space (Astronomy) to determine best time for rituals.

It's secondary purpose is to predict predisposition of people born at a certain time to determine compatibility with another man/woman for marriage (what is commonly known as Astrology or Janma Patrika or Jataka matching)

Today, Jyotisha has a mixed reputation in public because it is confused the with English word Astrology, because 'Astrologers' who did not duly study at a Veda Patashala/Gurukul, started making money by exploiting innocent people with half-baked knowledge and claims e.g. numerology, palmistry, zodiac predicitions etc.

The opportunists (atheist/rational/liberal/anti-Hindu) are also to blame, because they used the above problem to attack the scripture itself. It's like saying *'Modern medicine is bad, because some MBBS-fail doctors prescribed bad medicines'*

Jyotish is an exact science. A Vedic pundit in a village in India with a Panchaang (traditional Hindu almanac calendar), can predict exact eclipse times without complicated NASA telescopes.

- Just as you would not take medicine from a doctor who didn't pass MBBS from a reputed university, do not take Jyotisha advice from an astrologer who didn't pass Vedic education at a traditional Patashala.
- Just as you would not blame science due to some bad doctors, do not blame religion due to some bad actors.

Comment: @DarkKnight If you're satisfied with this answer, you can accept it by clicking on the tick mark (✓) below the voting buttons. if you like it you may press the up arrow for voting. That’s how the site knows whether the answer is satisfactory and answers the question askers questions.