# Is significance of Astrology mentioned and advocated in Hinduism Scripture?

Tags: astrology

Is anywhere the significance of astrology indicated in any of the Vedas or other documents and also whether it advocates the use of Astrology for finding remedies for the problems one faces in his life on earth?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is Astrology mentioned in Vedas?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/43916/is-astrology-mentioned-in-vedas)

Comment: Parasara brigd astrology look into part 2 last few chapters mention remedies. https://archive.org/details/BPHSEnglish/BPHS%20-%201%20RSanthanam/mode/2up