# Why do the vedas have hymns to worship demi gods (Agni, Indra, etc) but gita say not to worship demigods?

Tags: vedas, bhagavad-gita, moksha, demi-god

> अग्ने पवस्व स्वपा अस्मे वर्चस्सुवीर्यम् । दधद्रयिं मयि पोषम् ।।
>
> O Agni, The God of true deeds! Give us righteous valor and splendor of mind. Give to me Your riches and Your sustenance. - Rigveda 9.66.2
> अग्न आ याहि वीतये गृणानो हव्यदात्ये । नि होता सति्स बहिर्षि ।।
>
> O Agni! Come, accept our offerings. You are the One to whom we sing our songs. Convey our offerings to the Gods. You are the Priest for whom we have prepared the seat in our hearts. 
> पोषं रयीणामरिष्टिं तनूनां स्वाद् मानं वाच: सुदिनत्वमह्वाम् ।।
>
> It’s broad meaning is:
> O Indra! Give us the highest of riches, the skill and knowledge for action. Give us well-being and the vigor of vitality to our limbs. Protect us against injury. May we become sweet of speech and may our days be days that are full of light.

- Source: Rigveda 2.22.6

Not just this but there are many hymn that are dedicated to demi gods.

But in gita Shri krishna says:

> BG 7.20: Those whose knowledge has been carried away by material desires surrender to the celestial gods. Following their own nature, they worship the devatās, practicing rituals meant to propitiate these celestial personalities.
>
> BG 7.23: But the fruit gained by these people of small understanding is perishable. Those who worship the celestial gods go to the celestial abodes, while my devotees come to me.

Is Shri krishna indicating that people who only follow vedas can never achieve moksha?

Is Shri krishna indirectly rejecting vedas?

Actually my real question is why is Shri krishna opposing the vedas. That is my real question?

Comment: Before someone answers this question? You don’t respond to anyone’s comments/ participate in discussions on comments/ accept answers. Please, when someone posts an answer here, as the OP it is your duty to give feedback by accepting it and upvoting it. If someone is writing a valid comment on your questions they maybe explaining something it would be good to participate. Requesting you to kindly do the needful and sort your previous questions as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the meaning of worshiping a demigod? And is it bad to worship a demigod? \[BG 4.12\]](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11676/what-is-the-meaning-of-worshiping-a-demigod-and-is-it-bad-to-worship-a-demigod)

Comment: Ok but please answer my questions.

Comment: @DarkKnight I answered your question here: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/43915/20129  I have put a comment below the answer showing how you can accept it. Also for the answer to this question, check the link which snaps has given you. It has an answer below. It roughly answers this question of yours. Ram has also answers one question of yours : https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/43921/20129 I’ve explained there also how you can accept and vote. If you want something more from him please let him know he’ll surely give

Comment: Actually my real question is why is Shri krishna opposing the vedas. That is my real question